# Precedence of satisfiability operator

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm just reading a textbook in mathematical logic, as following:

[image]

What is the precedence to consider the equality and satisfiability operators in the equation pinpointed in red?! In other words, which of following cases right:

`(A \sat x) = y[s]` or `A \sat (x = y[s])`

Comment: Probably neither. I guess $s$ is an environment, i.e. a mapping from variables to members of the universe. In this case $\vDash$ is a ternary relation between a model, a formula, and an environment. The formula in the example is $x = y$.

Comment: But the book has been considered ⊨ as a binary operator. How could it be defined in a ternary semantic?

Comment: I don't know the book, so how can I answer this. But to interpret a FOL formula, you need to have a denotation of the formula's free variables. That's not given by the standard notion of) model. That's the purpose of the environment, or "assignment function".

Comment: Sorry.. You're right... The book is "A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Leary and Kristiansen.

Comment: Well, it's online [here](http://folk.uio.no/larsk/ch1.pdf#page=43). Indeed, $\vDash$ is a ternary relation in this book.